# Solve Max Velocity given Distance, Time, Initial velocity and final velocity

Tags: calculus, physics, kinematics

Following is known:
vInitial = 0 mm/s,
vFinal = 100 mm/s,
totalTime = 0.9 sec,
TotalDistance = 100 mm

How can I calculate the maximum velocity that will be reached, considering constant acceleration and deceleration (acc = -decc).

Edit:

[image: the solution I tried]

I was able to get equation with the help of answer from @Souparna
I am providing the equations, for future use if someone has the same query

[image]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have attached a picture for the solution i tried

Comment: So you have $2*100 = v_i t_1 + v_m (t_1+t_2) + v_f t_2$ and $t_1+t_2=.9$. But you haven't used that the acceleration and decelerations are the same yet. You haven't used $(v_m-v_i)/t_1$

Comment: if I try to use d = -a in the above equation then i get two unknows, T1 and Vmax.

Comment: That's only one unknown since $V_{max}=a T_1$

Comment: the acceleration is also unknown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At $t_1$, $v_{max}$ is achieved.
At $t=0.9 $, $v_f$ is achieved.
$$v_{max}=at_1$$
$$v_f=v_{max}-a(0.9-t_1)$$
$$s=\dfrac{1}{2}at_1^2+(0.9-t_1)v_{max}-\dfrac{1}{2}a(0.9-t_1)^2$$
From these we can get, $$v_f=100=at_1-a(0.9-t_1)\implies a=\dfrac{100}{2t_1-0.9}$$
$$s=100=\dfrac{1}{2}at_1^2+(0.9-t_1)at_1-\dfrac{1}{2}a(0.9-t_1)^2$$
Hence,$$100=\dfrac{50t_1^2}{2t_1-0.9}+\dfrac{100t_1(0.9-t_1)}{2t_1-0.9}+\dfrac{50(0.9-t_1)^2}{2t_1-0.9}$$
Solving we get $t_1=\dfrac{1}{20}(\sqrt{202}-2)\approx 0.61063$.
Hence, $a\approx 311.2675$ and $v_{max}\approx 190.0703$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it is incorrect.
t1 = 99/40 => 2.475 sec. t1 can not be greater than total time which is 0.9 sec.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are correct. But, that means the conditions are never satisfied. Where did you get the question? Do you have a solution?

Comment: Yes the Vmax should be 190.0703911308438 mm/s and t1 = 0.61063352017759487 s.

Comment: I have a .dll that calculates it but not the source code to it. I wanted to write the function by myself.

Comment: Using the values, $a=311.27$.
So, $s=0.5*311.27*0.61^2+0.9*311.27*0.61-0.5*311.27*(0.9-0.61)^2=215.7\neq 100$

Comment: I don't think the values are correct.

Comment: acc= 311.2675 mm/s^2,
t1 = 0.6106335 s,
t2 = 0.2894 s,
vMax = 190.0703911,
S1 = 0.5 * acc * t1^2 => 58.03166 mm,
S2 = (vMax * t2) - 0.5 * acc * t2^2 => (55.0063711 - 13.03469386) => 41.9716 mm,
S = S1 + S2 => 58.03166 + 41.9716 => 100.0032 (if u avoid rounding errors than will come exactly to 100 mm)

Comment: There was a mistake in my equation. Now, it matches your answer.

Comment: I was able to get the equation using the above solution. Thank you :)